# Quitting Emacs and re-enabeling touchpad

Tags: hooks, exit

I have the below elisp code in my emacs config which disables my touchpad, so it won't annoy me when writing.

```el
;; disable touchpad when on emacs

(defun turn-off-mouse (&optional frame)
  (interactive)
  (call-process-shell-command "xinput --disable bcm5974"
                              nil "*Shell command output*" t))

(defun turn-on-mouse (&optional frame)
  (interactive)
  (call-process-shell-command "xinput --enable bcm5974"
                              nil "*Shell command output*" t))

(add-hook 'focus-in-hook #'turn-off-mouse)
(add-hook 'focus-out-hook #'turn-on-mouse)
(add-hook 'delete-frame-functions #'turn-on-mouse)

(provide 'setup-xinput)
```

This works fine; the problem is only when quitting Emacs.

If I quit Emacs while on Emacs, it keeps my touchpad disabled. So I need to open a new Terminal with the keyboard, and run `xinput --enable bcm5974`.

Is there any workaround for this? How could I quit Emacs and when quitting re-enabling my touchpad?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `kill-emacs-hook` which is run when emacs is quit 'normally'.

> Hook run when `kill-emacs` is called. Since `kill-emacs` may be
>   invoked when the terminal is disconnected (or in other similar
>   situations), functions placed on this hook should not expect to be
>   able to interact with the user.  To ask for confirmation, see
>   `kill-emacs-query-functions` instead.

Just add `turn-on-mouse` to `kill-emacs-hook` like so

```el
(add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook #'turn-on-mouse)
```